# MVC 6 XML API post won't bind to model

Tags: asp.net, xml, http-post, asp.net-core-mvc

My eventual goal is to receive Twilio XML Posts when a new SMS is received, but for now I'm stuck on binding XML data to a model.

ASP.NET 5, MVC 6

I've enabled the XML formatters with:
`services.AddMvc().AddXmlDataContractSerializerFormatters().AddXmlSerializerFormatters();`

I have a simple model class:

```
public class XmlTest
{
    public string PropertyOne { get; set; }
    public string PropertyTwo { get; set; }
}
```

And a simple API method:

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Post(XmlTest xmlTest)
{
    //Application Logic
}
```

Using PostMan, I am posting this XML data:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<XmlTest>
   <PropertyOne>ValueOne</PropertyOne>
   <PropertyTwo>ghi789</PropertyTwo>
</XmlTest>
```

When the data is posted, xmlTest is initialized but the values of PropertyOne and PropertyTwo are not set.  If I add the `[FromBody]` attribute to XmlTest, then the value of xmlTest is null when the post occurs.

Can anyone help with what I'm doing wrong here?

JSON works just fine, but Twilio will only post xml.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you show us the HTTP Headers used when posting the XML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio evangelist here.

Just to make sure I understand what you are asking, you want to receive the parameters that Twilio sends to the MEssage Request URL when it receives a new message?

If I'm understanding that right, then there is no need to deal with XML.  The parameters that Twilio sends are form encoded values, so you handle them just like you would if you were posting values from an HTML form to your controller:

```
public ActionResult Incoming(string Body, string From, string To) {

    //you can return TwiML back to Twilio here or nothing

}
```

Hope that helps.